# PHP - Length of a number containing 0's to the left

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a number by it's length. This number has to have 4 digits so it passes the validation. The problem is when this number has 0's to it's left, like 0035.

Right now I'm at this:

```
echo (strlen ((string) 0025  ));
```

Which gives a total of 2, but I want this to count the 0's to it's left, so it gives me a total of 4.
Clearly the cast of the integer to string is not working, how can i do this?

Comment: <?php
$string = "0025";
echo (strlen($string));

Comment: Your problem is that you have a integer literal `0025`. PHP removes the leading zeroes before you cast it to a string. `strlen('0025')` will result in `4`.

Comment: The number is received as an integer, not as a string. I need to know that numbers length. I casted it to a string so i could use strlen, but it's not working.

Comment: How to you get the input? If it is through a HTTP Post it is a string and at some point you convert it to an integer.

Comment: Well actually IMHO your WSDL design is faulty if you NEED a number with a 4 digits, if it has to be this format a string would be a better way to represent the information. If any 4 digit number is valid why dont you check if the number is between `9999` and `0`. Formating it for displaying purpose is than another task. You could even use a string pattern to enforce a string that has the desired format.

Comment: Clenfort that would be my first choice, but the client wants this to be an integer...

Comment: Where is that number coming from to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that way, a left zero means the number is [octal and not decimal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), you can use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/sprintf) to do that.

Example:

```
echo strlen(sprintf("%04d", 25));
```

Live Test:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/VQr7Xz

### Comment Answer:

> I don't want to add the 0s to the number, i want to detect if the
> number has 0s. If the number received is 25, it's not a valid number.
> If it is 0025 it is valid. What i want is to validate only numbers
> with 4 digits. – Cláudio Ribeiro

Cláudio, numbers have infinite left zeros, although a user has explicitly type 2 or 3 left zeros there are more hidden left zeros, it's a math basic, this is why it's impossible to know how many left zeros the user has typed if you receive an `integer` variable. If the variable has a constant size and you want to know how many left zeros it has you can do this:

```
<?php
$int = 25;
 
echo  4 - strlen($int);
```

Live test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fT2jSn

But if you the variable has variable length it must be a `string` type instead of a `numeric` type.

An example where the variable received is a `string`:

```
<?php
$strs = array("0025","000035","01","2");
foreach($strs as $str)
{
    preg_match("/^0+/", $str, $matches);
    echo strlen(@$matches[0]);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Live Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BTRTgR

Comment: I don't want to add the 0s to the number, i want to detect if the number has 0s. If the number received is 25, it's not a valid number. If it is 0025 it is valid. What i want is to validate only numbers with 4 digits.

Comment: Thanks, i'm understanding the issue better now.

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```
$str = "0025";
if( is_numeric($str) && strlen($str) == 4)
{
    echo "pass";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *number*, not a string, the number doesn't have *digits*. It has a *value*. You can format that value into a string with 4 digits which is left padded with 0s. But to validate whether a number has 4 digits is nonsense, since the number *value* has no formatting. The value only becomes "4 digits" when you format it as base 10 number. Until then the value is a value which can be expressed in a multitude of bases and has a different number of "digits" in all of them.

You either want to format the number to a 0-padded 4 digit string, or you want to check whether the value is between 0 and 9999 (or 1000 and 9999 if it has to be exactly "4 digits").

```
if (0 <= $num && $num <= 9999) {
    $numStr = sprintf('%04d', $num);
} else {
    trigger_error('Number out of range');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i now understand it better. Still, i'm left with a problem in my hands. The client requirements have this problem.

Comment: And your job is to tell the client when he wants something that's not possible, or to talk it out with him until you're both on the same page about what you both want.